# PHP MongoDB\Client not accepting projection in query

Tags: php, mongodb, projection

I have a documents that contain large amounts of data I don't need for a particular query on a page, and I want to speed up the request.  When I perform the following query from the mongo shell:

```
db.hosts.find({},{dmiSystem: 1, networkInterfaces: 1, lanPrint: 1, pduPorts: 1})"
```

The mongo shell returns the fields I ask for almost instantly.  When I perform this same query from PHP using MongoDB\Client it takes about 5 seconds, the same amount of time as if I just ran a find() without any parameters.  Any ideas?  My code is:

```
$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$collection = $client->selectCollection("consoleServer", "hosts");
$rows = $collection->find(array(),array("_id" => 1, "dmiSystem" => 1,
                          "networkInterfaces" => 1, "lanPrint" => 1,
                          "pduPorts" => 1));
return $rows;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new MongoDB library for PHP uses another query syntax that looks more similar to Mongo Shell, using a projection variable.

Based in your example, you should be able to use something like this:

```
$rows = $collection->find(
      array(),
        'projection' => array(
           array(
             "_id" => 1, 
             "dmiSystem" => 1,
             "networkInterfaces" => 1, 
             "lanPrint" => 1,
             "pduPorts" => 1)
        )
    );
```

More information is available in the [Mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#php).

Comment: The "projection" variable was what was missing.  In the mongo shell, this is implied in the find() function's second argument, but in PHP this requires another level of associative array with "projection" specified.  Works well now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Find method needs 2 arrays. [@Henkealg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1105422/henkealg)'s answer has syntax error.

This is correct way to set projection and eg. limit:

```
$cursor = $collection->find(
    [],
    [
        'limit' => 5,
        'projection' => [
            '_id' => 1,
        ]
    ]
);
```

Be aware that you won't get error if you have typing error. Eg `projction` instead of `projection`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$rows = $collection->find(array(),
           array("projection" => array("_id" => 1, dmiSystem" => 1, "networkInterfaces" => 1, "lanPrint" => 1, "pduPorts" => 1)));`

Comment: could you please add bit more details and indent your code properly. :)